# How to auto insert the current user when creating an object in django Create template?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a database of articles with a

```
 User=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="Company_Owner",
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Where User is imported as follows:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User.
```

I would like to auto insert the current active user to the User field when a particular user submits the article.

I have done this in django admin:

```
class companyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
          if getattr(obj, 'User', None) is None:
              obj.User = request.user
          obj.save()
```

But it is changing for the superusers only if I login to django admin,it doesnot change for all users if I submit a form from template it doesnot return the specific user.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a template or form ?

Comment: You need to at least show the view where you create the article

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the Answer--

Done something like this in my view and it worked---

```
  class group1CreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
     form_class  = group1Form
     template_name = "accounting_double_entry/group1_form.html"

     def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.User = self.request.user
        return super(group1CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Thank you everyone for replying...It means a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You could override the **get_changeform_initial_data** of ModelAdmin class:

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    initial = {
        'user': request.user
    }

    return initial
```

You could also set other's fields initial values, if you'd like. This method is only called when you're adding an object. In its implementation, the default is to populate fields based on GET params:

**django.contrib.admin.options.py**

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    """
    Get the initial form data.
    Unless overridden, this populates from the GET params.
    """
    initial = dict(request.GET.items())
    for k in initial:
        try:
            f = self.model._meta.get_field(k)
        except FieldDoesNotExist:
            continue
        # We have to special-case M2Ms as a list of comma-separated PKs.
        if isinstance(f, models.ManyToManyField):
            initial[k] = initial[k].split(",")
    return initial
```

Edit: you could use the same logic if you want to implement this in a normal view. In this case, you would instantiate the ModelForm like this:

```
form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, initial={'user': request.user})
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is nothing need to do . `request.user` representing the currently logged-in user. If the user isn’t currently logged in, user will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser.

just write the view where a particular user submits the article.